# How to update nodes in a different Database or how to update external nodes ?- XDMP-UPEXTNODES

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I am trying to update a document in a different Database then my current DB. But it is giving me the below error-

```
XDMP-UPEXTNODES: xdmp:node-replace(fn:doc("/C:/Users/Downloads/abc.csv-0-2")/*:envelope/*:root/*:Status, <Status>1000</Status>) -- Cannot update external nodes
```

I am using the below code-

```
let $temp := 
  for $i in $result
  let $error := $i/*:envelope/*:ErrorMessage
  let $status := $i/*:envelope/*:Status
  return 
    if(fn:exists($i) eq fn:true()) then (
      xdmp:invoke-function(
        function() { 
          xdmp:node-replace($status,<Status>1000</Status>),
          xdmp:node-replace($error,<ErrorMessage>Change Error in other Database-2</ErrorMessage>)  
        },
        <options xmlns="xdmp:eval">
          <database>{xdmp:database("DATABASE-2")}</database>
        </options>))
    else ()
```

I want to update the Error and Status node of my **Database-2**.

$result is the document i fetched from **Database-2**.

This code i am running from **Database-1**

Any Suggestions ?

Comment: Why are you using two databases?

Comment: @grtjn- I am doing this for Datahub Framework and My Original Databse is STAGING and my document has to be modified in FINAL Database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot pass database nodes as variable for updating purposes like that. Instead you should pass through the database uri, and get a fresh copy of the element you'd like to update inside the invoked function. Maybe you can push a bit more logic inside the invoked function to make that easier. Something like:

```
for $i in $result
let $uri := xdmp:node-uri($i)
return xdmp:invoke-function(function() {
  let $doc := fn:doc($uri)
  let $error := $doc/*:envelope/*:ErrorMessage
  let $status := $doc/*:envelope/*:Status
  return if(fn:exists($doc) eq fn:true()) then (
    xdmp:node-replace($status, <Status>1000</Status>),
    xdmp:node-replace($error, <ErrorMessage>Change Error in other Database-2</ErrorMessage>)
  ) else ()
}, map:entry("database", xdmp:database("DATABASE-2")))
```

Be careful though. It sounds like $i is pointing to the actual document in Database-2 as well, and it could easily result in dead-locks; the invoking query could be putting a read lock on $i, causing the invoked function to be unable to update it.

HTH!

Comment: @grtjn- I tried the same code but still it is giving me the similar error.

Comment: @Shalini Can you add the code you are now trying to your question?

Comment: @RobS.It worked for me later on :). Actually i wrote the code outside of the xdmp:invoke before but now it is working correctly.