# How to execute the conditions Sequentially in MarkLogic?

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I am having a requirement where i need to check certain conditions and after all conditions got checked- I need to insert the document in **Database-2** with FLAG value as "True".

The code is as below-

```
for $i in cts:search(doc(),cts:collection-query(("MyCollection")))
     return
 let $condition_1 := if{...} then <Flag>FALSE</Flag> else ()
 let $condition_2 := if{...} then <Flag>FALSE</Flag> else ()
 let $condition_3 := if{...} then <Flag>FALSE</Flag> else ()
 let $condition_4 := if{...} then <Flag>FALSE</Flag> else ()
```

Once i will execute all the conditions then these conditions will alter my **FLAG** node from **"True" to "False"** as shown in the above code.

At last i need to check which ever document is having `<Flag>True</Flag>` i need to insert only those document to **Database-2**.

I am running this code from **Database-1**.

Any Suggestions ?

Answer (score 2):

You can also use XQuery's [quantified expressions](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/XQuery/Quantified_Expressions) in cases like this:

```
for $i in cts:search(doc(), cts:collection-query(("MyCollection")))
where every $check in (
    (...), 
    (...)
) satisfies $check

return xdmp:invoke-function(etc)
```

Where `...` still represents an expression that returns a boolean. Instead of `every`, you might want `not(some $check in (..., ...) satisfies $check)`.

Answer (score 1):

I typically find it's easiest to do this type of stacked condition checking where all conditions must be true in XQuery with this technique using a map:

```
let $conditionMap = map:map();
let $_ := map:put($conditionMap, "check", fn:false())
let $condition_1 := if{...} then () else map:put($conditionMap, "check", fn:true())
let $condition_2 := if{...} then () else map:put($conditionMap, "check", fn:true())
let $condition_3 := if{...} then () else map:put($conditionMap, "check", fn:true())
let $condition_4 := if{...} then () else map:put($conditionMap, "check", fn:true())

let $flag := <Flag>{if(map:get($conditionMap, "check") eq fn:false()) then "FALSE" else "TRUE"}</Flag>

let $documentInsert := ...
```

An alternative technique (I find more efficient but less readable) is:

```
let $flag :=
 if($condition_1) then
  if($condition_2) then
   if($condition_3) then
    if($condition_4) then <Flag>TRUE</flag>
    else <Flag>FALSE</flag>
   else <Flag>FALSE</flag>
  else <Flag>FALSE</flag>
 else <Flag>FALSE</flag>

let $documentInsert := ...
```

You can probably put the documentInsert piece together [from your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51357037/how-to-update-nodes-in-a-different-database-or-how-to-update-external-nodes-x).

Answer (score 0):

If you have conditions that evaluate to boolean, then just evaluate the boolean result of all of those conditions, convert that to a string, and then use `fn:upper-case()` to get it's upper-case value:

```
for $i in cts:search(doc(), cts:collection-query(("MyCollection")))
let $condition_1 := {...} 
let $condition_2 := {...} 
let $condition_3 := {...} 
let $condition_4 := {...} 
return
  <Flag>{ 
    fn:upper-case(fn:string( ($condition_1 and $condition_2 and $condition_3 and $condition_4)) 
  }</Flag>
```